# Highlight all active items in nested menu (AngularJS, ui-router)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJS with ui-router for my website.
I have a multi-level menu (when you select one item, you can see next menu's level)

home | about | **contact us**

NY | **LA** | SF

Street1 | Street2 | **Street3**

So, at this example we looking at Street3 details, in LA in Contact us page. All selected items is active.
I can't make it with ui-router's `ui-sref-active="active"` because it's highlight only last item (Street3) Other items are not active, but should be.
Are there any ideas to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `$state.includes(stateName)` to check if the current active state is equal to or is the child of the state `stateName`. Combine it with `ng-class`, you will get to highlight the correct tabs.

Here is a [working example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/japBuczSqc1PtUgNoTgF?p=preview)